# Java Cloud Function access to Pre-Set Environment variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Using Java 11 Run time for my GCP Cloud Function as a trigger from GCS.

NodeJS and Python runtimes have access to a few useful preset environment variables as documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#nodejs_6_nodejs_8_python_37_and_go_111)

But they are not available for JAVA. Any updates when we will have the same variables available for JAVA 11 runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

As of now (2020/09/18), there are some environment variables set by default, you can show them with a simple Java Cloud Function (example with HTTP function) :

```java
package com.example;

import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;

public class Example implements HttpFunction {
  @Override
  public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws Exception {
    System.getenv().entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

The logs are showing :

```
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin 
LANGUAGE=en_US:en 
PORT=8080 
FUNCTION_SIGNATURE_TYPE=http 
K_SERVICE=function-1 
K_REVISION=2 
LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
X_GOOGLE_MEMORY_HINT_DO_NOT_USE=256 
DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive 
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-XX:MaxRAM=256m -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=70 
PWD=/srv 
FUNCTION_TARGET=com.example.Example 
SHLVL=0 
HOME=/root
```

But, [as recommended by best practices](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var#best_practices_and_reserved_environment_variables) :

> Environment variables that are provided by the environment (other than the ones listed in Environment variables set automatically) might change in future runtime versions. As a best practice, we recommend that you do not depend on or modify any environment variables that you have not set explicitly.

If you want to know about the future of environment variables in Java 11 runtime, I think you should try asking directly to Google via their [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: Thank you. I was more keen at Project-id which is available with node.js and python